# MSSQL and PHP - mssql_get_last_message and stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server

Does mssql_get_last_message return any values after procedure is finished? Does it return anything if procedure fails to finish?

Comment: Have you considered checking the PHP manual once.

Comment: Can you quote the answer please.